# JQuery Mobile data-native-menu="false" throws an undefined error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Working on styling a menu with jquery mobile through a select list. The problem is, adding a data-native-menu="false" as an option throws an error when I append it to the header. The snippet of code that works is this:

```
var menu = '<div class="ui-select"><select name="menu-items" class="menu-items"  id="menu-items"  tabindex="-1" data-native-menu="false" >';
        menu += '<option value="a">A</option> <option value="b">A</option>';
        menu += '</select></div>'; 
$("div[data-role='header']", this.el).html(menu).trigger('create');
```

That error that it generates is this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jQuery18303288714927621186' of undefined
```

In the example below, I removed the data-native-menu and it will work But the UI does not look at intended:

```
var menu = '<div class="ui-select"><select name="menu-items" class="menu-items"  id="menu-items"  tabindex="-1"  >';
        menu += '<option value="a">A</option> <option value="b">A</option>';
        menu += '</select></div>'; 
$("div[data-role='header']", this.el).html(menu).trigger('create');
```

What could be causing this problem?

Comment: What's your jquery-mobile version do you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html><head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>data-natice-menu</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile.structure-1.2.0.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) { 
    var menu = '<div class="ui-select"><select name="menu-items" class="menu-items"  id="menu-items"  tabindex="-1" data-native-menu="false" >';
    menu += '<option value="a">A</option> <option value="b">A</option>';
    menu += '</select></div>'; 
    $("div[data-role='header']", this.el).html(menu).trigger('create');
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="page">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**: I changed the code. I tested it and it shows select correctly.